# How to install enterprise .IPA file generated by expo in iPhone?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I’m new to expo and I’m trying to build an app for iOS for a firm. I already have an Apple Enterprise
 Account. With that I build .IPA for my app using “expo build : iOS” and I let the expo to
 handle all the certificate generation process.

My expo build : iOS was succeeded (100%) without any error and I am having .IPA file in my hand.

The problem comes here when I open the .IPA in iPhone it is not showing any installation option. So I 
tried to extract the archive .IPA file. It has folder structure Payload > ExpoKitApp.app. With in
 that .app folder I having all the necessary files related to my app.

I don’t know how to manually install the .IPA file in my iPhone. Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can drag the IPA file to your phone using iTunes or the Finder integration or you can serve a manifest file that references your IPA.  This must be from an HTTPS server

Comment: Finally installed.Thanks.

Comment: @Dhinesh KS can you please post how you installed it on an iPhone as an answer. I am trying to do it as well but it is failing.

Comment: @ SachinKumar
The generated IPA will be an archieve file. Which you can't directly install on the device. Please refer the link below

https://mobikul.com/install-ipa-file-iphone-device/

I have used diawi for installation. Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? Now, I have the same issue. Thanks